# Change value of div with new entry and don't append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am totally new to coding. Please help.I am obtaining tweet text using node.js and displaying using html. When I input new text the result should replace earlier result in #tweets and not append to it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>

<body>

    <form>
       #<input type="text" id="tag" class="hash"/>
       <button>submit</button>
   </form>
   <div id="tweets"></div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
   <script>
   var socket = io.connect('/link');

   $('.hash').on('keypress',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#tweet').empty();
        socket.emit('message', $('#tag').val());
    },2000);

    return;
    });

   socket.on('message', function(msg){
        $('#tag').val('');
        $('#tweet').empty();
        $('#tweets').after($('<div>').text(msg));
    });

   </script>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.after` with [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$('#tweets').html($('<div>').text(msg));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly just use `text` or `innerHTML`.
For Example:

```
...
socket.on('message', function(msg){
        $('#tag').val('');
        $('#tweet').html(msg); //OR
        $('#tweet').text(msg);

    });
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there also perhaps a misspelled JQuery selector? I cannot find the element "#tweet." It appears in both your timeout and in the socket event handler. I'd personally go with this instead, esp if there *is* a selector spelling issue.

```
$("<div />", {
    text: msg
}).appendTo($("#tweets").empty());
```

**EDIT:** I like SlyBeaver's gist. I thought you needed an inner div for some reason. Rather than deal with `.empty().append().chain().a().bunch().of().stuff()`, I'd just do for plain text:

```
$("#tweets").text(msg);
```

**or** if the tweet contains HTML, use this or it will not be parsed as such:

```
$("#tweets").html(msg);
```

Comment: This answer assumes that you wanted the inner DIV -- oh, wait... Did you?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $('#tweets').after($('<div>').text(msg));
```

to use `.html()` in jquery

```
$('#tweets').html($('<div>').text(msg));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('tweets').innerHTML = 'Your content';
```